# Rails 3 undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an accounts resource. When going to `/accounts/new`, I get:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

The error is on line 1 in new.html.haml. Here's my code:

My view: `new.html.haml`

```
1. = form_for @account do |f| 
2.   - if @account.errors.any?
       #error_explanation
3. ......
```

My controller `new` method:

```
def new
  @account = Account.new
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you have defined Account class correctly? Maybe there is a spelling error there?

Comment: Controller: `class AccountsController < ApplicationController`
Model: `class Account < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: And you ran the migrations?

Comment: Also make sure you restart your server.

Comment: I did run migrations and I restarted the server.

Comment: Did you try to debug `@account` after defining it.

Comment: What happens if you change `@account` in your view to `Account.new`?

Comment: Same error. I just removed the entire model and re-created it.

Comment: Hmm, that makes no sense. Are you certain `Account.new` gives you the same nil error and not a different error such as `uninitialized constant` or `count not find table`. The only thing that I can think of that might cause that to happen is if you for some reason define a class level `new` method, or scope in your account model that returns nil.

Comment: I agree; it's unlikely the error is occurring precisely as you describe. You can put a `binding.pry` (if you're using `pry`, which you probably should be) immediately after the account creation and see what's actually in `@account`. If the `pry` isn't hit, then you're either in the wrong controller, aren't running what you think you are, or the world is coming to an end.

Comment: Are you sure that it is really this controller which is handling the request? Maybe you have another controller similar spelled and this view is rendered by it?